# Where is the cyclops eye? I killed the cyclops but he didn't drop anything

Tags: chronos

Killed cyclops. The blacksmith still tells me "Tis as I feared. You do not have the eye. The task is hopeless." 
I checked my inventory after I killed him but nothing was added after I killed him. and I couldn't loot the body because I was teleported away as soon as he died.
I went back but nothing was in the room.
HELP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's nothing to do with the giant cyclops.  It's some golum under the statue in the area where the guys on stilts are.

Here is a picture of the statue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAERc.jpg

To open the area under the statue you need the item from this box: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ozdi.jpg

This game is hard to describe areas.

It depends on solving this one first:

[How do you open the gold sliding mask puzzle box?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261521/how-do-you-open-the-gold-sliding-mask-puzzle-box)