# How do you open the gold sliding mask puzzle box?

Tags: chronos

How do you open the sliding mask puzzle box in the area with the krell on stilts?

Here is a picture:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turn the combination of horns mask and clothing to match this statue:

[image: example]

like this:

[image: screenshot]

Then take the item it gives you and place it in front of the horned statue.